# PartitionProblem variation - fixed size of subsets

Tags: dynamic-programming, np-complete, subset-sum, partition-problem

I have a problem which is a variation of the partition problem which is NP-complete. This is an optimization problem, not a decision problem.

**Problem**: Partition a list of numbers into two subsets such that their difference of sums is minimum, and find the two subsets. If `n` even, then the sizes should be `n/2`, and if odd, then `floor[n/2]` and `ceil[n/2]`.

Assuming that the pseudo polynomial time DP algorithm is the best for an *exact* solution, how can it be modified to solve this? And what would be the best *approximate* algorithms to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't specified which algorithm to use i'll assume you use the one defined here:
http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~wdtseng/icpc/notes/dp3.pdf

Then using this algorithm you add a variable to track the best result, initialize it to `N` (sum of all the numbers in the list as you can always take one subset to be the empty set) and every time you update `T` (e.g: T[i]=true) you do something like `bestRes = abs(i-n/2)<bestRes : abs(i-n/2) : bestRes`. And you return `bestRes`. This of course doesn't change the complexity of the algorithm.

I've got no idea about your 2nd question.